# undo is sorely lacking... where to fix?

Tags: undo

Lately (not sure when / what release) my undo function has just become almost useless. It unpredictably fails to work even for a single step sometimes.

I know there are some undo-related settings somewhere which I can't find just now, but I'm reasonably sure I set it to generous levels last time I was there.

I did see another post about this, but it's five years out of date. Anyone have any current advice? I have V12 in case it matters.

Comment: I find undo works well in V12. I suggest that you find a simple example that works in an empty notebook, specify the exact sequence of keys you press and provide screenshots before and after pressing control z. Also, you should state your operating system and version.

Comment: I’ve noticed that sometimes if the edit was a bit too drastic, undo fails to work occasionally.